# Continuous map from Sierpinski space to Hausdorff space is constant map

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove following theorem

> Let $S$ be the Sierpinski space and $Y$ a Hausdorff space. Show that every continuous map $f: S \rightarrow Y$ is a constant map.

First state my strategy. I am trying to show that continuous map is constant map. First what I know is the open set in Sierpinski space is follows : $T= \{ \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \phi\}$,

From the assumption, $Y$ is a Hausdorff, so for $x\neq y$, $\exists$ $U_x, V_y$ with $x\in U_x, y\in V_y, U_x\cap V_y = \phi$.

I tried to make up with $f^{-1}(U_x)$, $f^{-1}(V_y)$ is open and $f^{-1}(U_x \cap V_y) = f^{-1} (\phi)$ is open. But this is not enough for showing constancy of map $f$.

How I can show the constancy of map $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f: S \to Y$ is **not** constant. This means that $f(a) \neq f(b)$, as $S$ only has the two points $\{a,b\}$. Now we need to apply Hausdorffness so there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that

$$f(a) \in U, f(b) \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset\text{.}$$

This implies that $b \in f^{-1}[V]$ and this set is open, as $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}[V]=S$, as the only open set containing $b$ is $S$. But then $f(a) \in V$ too, which is a contradiction.

Generalisation: if $S$ is a space such that $$\forall U,V \text{ open }: U \neq \emptyset \land V \neq \emptyset \to U \cap V \neq \emptyset$$

(so all non-empty open sets intersect), then any continuous $f: S \to Y$ is constant when $Y$ is Hausdorff. The Sierpiński space obeys that property, among other spaces, like the cofinite topology on an infinite set, or the trivial topology.

Answer (score 2):

If you know about [specialization orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order), here is a short proof. The specialization order on the Sierpińsky space is given by $a \leqslant b$, but the specialization order of a Hausdorff space is the equality relation. Now, every continuous map is monotone for the specialization orders. Thus, if $Y$ is Hausdorff and $f: T \to Y$ is continuous, $a \leqslant b$ implies $f(a) = f(b)$. Thus $f$ is a constant map.

It is interesting to compare this argument with Henno Brandsma's answer, since it leads to a kind of dual generalisation: if the specialization order on $Y$ is the equality, then every continuous map from $T$ to $Y$ is constant. For instance, if $Y$ is an infinite set equipped with the cofinite topology, every continuous function $f:T \to Y$ is constant.