# True / False on Continuous Function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In my lecture note about Compactness, there is an exercise below.

> Let $(\mathbb{N}, \mathscr{T})$ be a space where $\mathscr{T}$ consists of  $\emptyset, \mathbb{N} $ and $E_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove or disprove that every continuous function $f : (\mathbb{N}, \mathscr{T}) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a constant function.

I have checked that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is compact. But I have no idea what to do to solve this question. Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $1\ne n\in \Bbb N$ with $f(n)\ne f(1).$  Let $r=|f(n)-f(1)|/2.$  Now the set $S=f^{-1}(-r+f(n),r+f(n))$ is not in $\mathscr {T},$ because $1\not \in S\ne \emptyset.$ So $f $ is not continuous.

Comment: Overkill method: Theorem: Let $X$ be any space and let $D$ be a dense subset of $X$. Let $Y$ be a Hausdorff space. If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ are continuous and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in D$, then $f=g$.... Apply this with $X=(\Bbb N, \mathscr T)$ and $Y=\Bbb R$ and $D=\{1\}$ and let $g(n)=f(1)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

Answer (score 2):

The definition of continuity states that the preimage of every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ must be open in $(\mathbb{N},\mathscr{T})$. In particular, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ must be open, i.e., $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \in \mathscr{T}$. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: Thanks for the great comment! The given topology is actually not trivial, but I got that the statement can be disproved in s similar way as you wrote. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SeokBeomKim My mistake, I missed the $E_n$ sets. Glad it helped anyway

Answer (score 1):

Note that any two non-empty open sets in the domain intersect. Abuse Hausdorffness of $\Bbb R$ to show a continuous $f$ with at least two distinct values cannot exist. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3440529/4280), e.g.

Answer (score 1):

The main observation is that the only infinite set in $\mathscr{T}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ itself.

Assume that the image of $f$ contains at least 2 points, say $a,b\in f(\mathbb{N})$ where $a<b$.

Now since $f(\mathbb{N})$ is countable and $(a,b)$ is not, then there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $c\not\in f(\mathbb{N})$. Therefore

$$\mathbb{N}=A\cup B$$

for $A:=f^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ and $B:=f^{-1}((c,\infty))$.

Both $A$ and $B$ are open (by continuity), nonempty, disjoint (by construction) and one of them has to be infinite (because their union is $\mathbb{N}$). WLOG assume that $A$ is infinite. Since open sets in $\mathscr{T}$ are finite except for $\mathbb{N}$ itself then $A=\mathbb{N}$. But then there is no choice for $B$ making them both nonempty and disjoint. Contradiction. $\Box$